# Updating android api in sdk manager

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I'm going to install new version of android api from my sdk manager.. but I do not use avd .. I always test my apps with genymotion.. So I don't know which packages should be downloaded and which one shouldn't.. or this has nothing to do with that and I have to download all of them, could you help me please ?

[image]

Comment: not an issue . download all of them .

Comment: @Radhey, not if you have a limited 1 Mbit/s connection.

Comment: agree with you @VladMatvienko , all packages are not mandatory like #Android Wear (if you are not developing any wearable app) ,but for the ease of use I suggest to download all packages.

Comment: @VladMatvienko is right . required package is #SDK platform for particular API level , and inside #extrs there is support repository .you can find exact info. from here https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SDK platform` only is required. Everything else is optional.
 Also don't forget to update support libraries at least to the version of SDK you will use, so if you use SDK 25, support libraries version has to be not less than 25.0.0

Comment: You mean everything except  #1 is about AVD ?

Comment: @Majid almost. #9 is the Android sources

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you don't have any of these installed and you try to run your project in Android Studio, Android Studio will suggest you to download and install the ones needed.

I think only the compileSdkVersion is needed.

Answer (score -2):

press the sdk manager button at the menu and update all the api's.